# how do I take user input data as a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

So in my algorithm Im using a variable to store some graph nodes. But I want to make it as an user input.

```
parents = {'N1': ['N2', 'N3', 'N4'], 'N3': ['N6', 'N7'], 'N4': ['N3'], 'N5': ['N4', 'N8'], 'N6': ['N13'], 'N8': ['N9'], 'N9': ['N11'], 'N10': ['N7', 'N9'], 'N11': ['N14'], 'N12': ['N5']}
```

The code above should look like:

```
parents = list(input("Enter vertices:"))
```

But this only makes a list. I need a dict of lists.

Comment: Is the user input a string like `{'N1': ['N2', 'N3', 'N4'], 'N3': ['N6', 'N7'], 'N4': ['N3'], 'N5': ['N4', 'N8'], 'N6': ['N13'], 'N8': ['N9'], 'N9': ['N11'], 'N10': ['N7', 'N9'], 'N11': ['N14'], 'N12': ['N5']}`?

Comment: Yes. Should be able to input that.

Comment: I don't understand what is the question here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert a string that represents a Python literal into a proper Python object using the `ast` module's [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). From the docs:

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
>   literal or container display. The string or node provided may only
>   consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes,
>   numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python
>   values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values
>   oneself. It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex
>   expressions, for example involving operators or indexing.

```
from pprint import pprint
from ast import literal_eval

s = "{'N1': ['N2', 'N3', 'N4'], 'N3': ['N6', 'N7'], 'N4': ['N3'], 'N5': ['N4', 'N8'], 'N6': ['N13'], 'N8': ['N9'], 'N9': ['N11'], 'N10': ['N7', 'N9'], 'N11': ['N14'], 'N12': ['N5']}"

parents = literal_eval(s)

pprint(parents)
```

**output**

```
{'N1': ['N2', 'N3', 'N4'],
 'N10': ['N7', 'N9'],
 'N11': ['N14'],
 'N12': ['N5'],
 'N3': ['N6', 'N7'],
 'N4': ['N3'],
 'N5': ['N4', 'N8'],
 'N6': ['N13'],
 'N8': ['N9'],
 'N9': ['N11']}
```

There's also a built-in function called [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) which *could* do this, but you should **never** use `eval` on untrusted user input because it's not secure.

---

Here's how to use `literal_eval` on user input:

```
from pprint import pprint
from ast import literal_eval

s = input('Enter a node dictionary: ')
parents = literal_eval(s)
pprint(parents)
```

**demo**

```
Enter a node dictionary: {'N1': ['N2', 'N3', 'N4'], 'N3': ['N6', 'N7'], 'N4': ['N3'], 'N5': ['N4', 'N8'], 'N6': ['N13'], 'N8': ['N9'], 'N9': ['N11'], 'N10': ['N7', 'N9'], 'N11': ['N14'], 'N12': ['N5']}
{'N1': ['N2', 'N3', 'N4'],
 'N10': ['N7', 'N9'],
 'N11': ['N14'],
 'N12': ['N5'],
 'N3': ['N6', 'N7'],
 'N4': ['N3'],
 'N5': ['N4', 'N8'],
 'N6': ['N13'],
 'N8': ['N9'],
 'N9': ['N11']}
```

Comment: Sir, you got my question wrong. My parents variable stores that dict, right ? I do not want it to store a specific dict. I want that it would store a user input that looks like above dict.

Comment: @Dan: The understanding is that `s` actually comes from an `input()` call. `literal_eval` will process it anyway.

Comment: @Dan My code converts a string into a Python object. You can read the string from `input()` if you want. I just put the string into my code to illustrate the process.

Comment: @Dan Please see my updated answer. That should make things clearer.